# PHP - Access folder shared network

Tags: php, directory, shared

I can access to the every server from my shared network with my user account.

I wrote a PHP Script in Wamp and want to access to a folder of my shared network.

I can access to it directly with their direct path : \128.xx.3.199\share\GMSA

But it doesn't work with my script:

```
<?php
$try =  '\\\\128.xx.3.199\share\GMSA\Test';
        var_dump( glob( $try . '\*.*' ) );
        var_dump( scandir( $try ) );
```

I think it's because Wamp hasn't the same permission than the current user account. But don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption could be right. Try the following:

- Open 'Component Services' in Windows
- Choose 'Services' and on the right navigate to the wampapache service (64 or 86)
- Open the service, choose 'Log On' and change from 'Local System Account' to 'My Account'
- Enter your credentials, apply and restart the service.

Comment: If I could give you 50k points, I would do! Thank you so much! Works like a charm

Comment: But what about programmatically? Is it possible to fopen with username and password? exec(net use...) and fopen is not working

Comment: on my case that still not worck